# Signin Error to Tableau Server using Python Migration SDK

Tags: python, tableau-api, tableau-cloud

I'm encountering a "SignIn Error" while attempting to migrate from an on-premises Tableau server to Tableau Online using a personal access token (PAT). I suspect the issue might be related to the URL or site content URL configuration.

```py
import tableau_migration
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import configparser
from tableau_migration.migration_engine import PyMigrationPlanBuilder
from tableau_migration.migration_engine_migrators import PyMigrator
from threading import Thread

load_dotenv()

# Access environment variables
on_prem_token_name = os.environ.get("on_prem_token_name")
on_prem_private_token = os.environ.get("on_prem_private_token")
cloud_token_name = os.environ.get("cloud_token_name")
cloud_private_token = os.environ.get("cloud_private_token")

# Read configuration from config.ini
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Output all the inputs read by the config reader
for section in config.sections():
    print(f"Section: {section}")
    for option in config.options(section):
        value = config.get(section, option)
        first_three_letters = value[:3] if len(value) >= 3 else value
        print(f"  Option: {option}, Value: {first_three_letters}, Len: {len(value)}")

def migrate_single_workbook():
    
    # Initialize migration plan builder and migrator
    plan_builder = PyMigrationPlanBuilder()
    migrator = PyMigrator()

    # Read configuration from config.ini
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')

    # Build the migration plan
    plan = plan_builder \
        .from_source_tableau_server(
            server_url=config['SOURCE']['URL'], 
            site_content_url=config['SOURCE']['SITE_CONTENT_URL'],
            access_token_name=config['SOURCE']['ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME'], 
            access_token=on_prem_private_token)\
        .to_destination_tableau_cloud(
            pod_url=config['DESTINATION']['URL'],
            site_content_url=config['SOURCE']['SITE_CONTENT_URL'],
            access_token_name=config['DESTINATION']['ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME'],
            access_token=cloud_private_token
        ) \
        .for_server_to_cloud() \
        .with_tableau_id_authentication_type() \
        .with_tableau_cloud_usernames(config['USERS']['EMAIL_DOMAIN']) \
        .build()
    
    # Execute the migration plan
    results = migrator.execute(plan)

    # Handle migration results
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        
    return plan

# Create a thread to run the migration
migration_thread = Thread(target=migrate_single_workbook)
migration_thread.start()

# Wait for the migration to complete or handle interruption
while True:
    try:
        migration_thread.join(1)
        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Migration interrupted. Cleaning up...")
        # Cleanup resources if needed
        break
```

Error Message:

```
An error occurred during migration. Error: Tableau.Migration.Api.Rest.RestException: An error was returned from the Tableau API:
URL: <both websites throwing the same error>
Code: 401001
Summary: Signin Error
Detail: Error signing in to Tableau Server
```

Environment:

- Python 3.11.5
- Running on an AWS cloud VM

Additional Details:
I've verified that the personal access token (PAT) and other environment variables are correctly set up by printing them out. However, I suspect that the issue might be related to the URL or site content URL configuration in my config.ini file (tried various variants).

```
[SOURCE]
URL = https://tableau.website.com/
SITE_CONTENT_URL = #/site/projects/87
ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME = access_token_name

[DESTINATION]
URL = https://prod-us-b.online.tableau.com/#/site/tableaucompanywebsite
SITE_CONTENT_URL = 
ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME = cloud_access_token_name

[USERS]
EMAIL_DOMAIN = company.com
```

Request for Assistance:

I'm unsure about the correctness of the URL and site content URL configurations, especially considering the naming convention that includes a '#' in the URL. Overall, unsure about the code or process in general after reading the docs. I suspect that I don't have the SITE_CONTENT_URL correct, but I'm not sure how to resolve the 'SignIn Error'. Any guidance on troubleshooting or correcting these configurations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the URLs and the environment variables you are setting.

The config.ini should be something like

```ini
[SOURCE]
URL = https://tableau.website.com/
SITE_CONTENT_URL =  <-- blank if it is the default site. Otherwise, put the sitename here
ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME = actual_server_token_name

[DESTINATION]
URL = https://prod-us-b.online.tableau.com/
SITE_CONTENT_URL = tableaucompanywebsite
ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME = actual_cloud_token_name
```

Set the below environment variables for tokens (instead of `on_prem_private_token` and `cloud_private_token`). Remember they need to be set before you run the Python script.

`TABLEAU_MIGRATION_DESTINATION_TOKEN`
`TABLEAU_MIGRATION_DESTINATION_TOKEN`

You can follow the code [on Github](https://github.com/tableau/tableau-migration-sdk/blob/main/tests/Python.TestApplication/main.py#L148) for guidance.
That code uses json based config for the stuff other than the tokens but you don't have to do that.